# How to convert a WebView2 to HtmlDocument?

Tags: c#, html, dom, webbrowser-control, webview2

I want to convert my old webBrowser API to the new webView2 API.

```
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser.Document.OpenNew(false);
doc.Write(sResponse);
var resultAsString = (string)doc.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { "window.validate" });
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You can use `NavigateToString` to load your html string.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use NavigateToString and ExecuteScriptAsync

```
webBrowser.NavigateToString(sResponse);
var scriptResult = await webBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("window.validate");
```